# How to enable the user to maximize my window and keep the window with his proportions?

Tags: c#, wpf

when a user presses the full-screen button all of the items stays in the upper left corner.
i want to prevent this and keep the window as-is just in full-screen.

Comment: are you using margin property for your controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full Screen Mode**

**C# :**

```
WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

**XAML :**

```
< Window ... WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized" ... />
```

---

**Kepping Windows Proportions**

**XAML :**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />         // Auto Rule
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />            // Star Rule
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />          // Fixed Rule
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />       // Auto Rule
        <ColumnDefinition Height="*" />         // Star Rule
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />        // Fixed Rule
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

**Rules :**

- Fixed

  Fixed size of logical units (1/96 inch)
- Auto

  Takes as much space as needed by the contained control
- Star

  Takes as much space as available (after filling all auto and fixed sized columns)

Grid lets you enjoy both worlds - As long as you're putting all elements into a single cell, you get both: Arbitrary positioning and auto-sizing.

Please refer to this [tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/gridlayout.html), for using Rows and Columns

Answer (score 0):

you just put all items with in canvas and then margin it where you want to place.

Answer (score 0):

```
WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None; 
WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

use the anchor properties of the controls, and the docking properties associated with that controls